# Facebook sharer strange bug

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

If I share the following URL, it works fine and posts to my wall;

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=https://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/about&p[images][0]=&p[title]=Test%20Title&p[summary]=This%20is%20a%20test
```

But this URL doesn't work, it just refreshes the `sharer.php` page;

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=https://www.facebook.com/Google&p[images][0]=&p[title]=Test%20Title&p[summary]=This%20is%20a%20test
```

Does anyone know why?  Is it forbidden to share Facebook pages using the sharer?

Comment: Yes - Facebook is returning an HTTP 500 error. This seems to be a problem on their side. You should wait a little bit and try again. Failing that, I recommend that you [open a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/).

Comment: I tested again and it's still not working, so I submitted a bug and it was accepted; https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/1453000781579187/

Comment: Great that you posted a link back to the bug here! Good job! Lets hope they deal with it fast.